# Django - Attempting to deploy app on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I am attempting to deploy a Django app on Heroku. The instance appears to start and I see the following in the logs when it starts:

```
2023-04-28T15:36:03.694071+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn config.wsgi -- logfile -`
2023-04-28T15:36:05.869274+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-04-28 15:36:05 +0000] [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
2023-04-28T15:36:05.869477+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-04-28 15:36:05 +0000] [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:14398 (2)
2023-04-28T15:36:05.869516+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-04-28 15:36:05 +0000] [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2023-04-28T15:36:05.871197+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-04-28 15:36:05 +0000] [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2023-04-28T15:36:05.908573+00:00 app[web.1]: [2023-04-28 15:36:05 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2023-04-28T15:36:06.373542+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2023-04-28T15:36:07.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

However, when I attempt to visit the site (at the Heroku provided URL) I see the following error in the browser:

```
Not Found

The requested resource was not found on this server.
```

I see this in the Heroku logs:

```
2023-04-28T15:37:50.232938+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.55.214 - - [28/Apr/2023:15:37:50 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0"
2023-04-28T15:37:50.233993+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=sitename.herokuapp.com request_id=77318e40-99f5-47bd-9f29-f828ab07097f fwd="71.81.213.118" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=293ms status=404 bytes=343 protocol=https
2023-04-28T15:42:26.163509+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=sitename.herokuapp.com request_id=b6490fc8-a242-4214-a39d-657f0e295f68 fwd="71.81.213.118" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=119ms status=404 bytes=343 protocol=https
2023-04-28T15:42:26.163514+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.50.56 - - [28/Apr/2023:15:42:26 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0"
2023-04-28T15:48:19.193500+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.85.46 - - [28/Apr/2023:15:48:19 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0"
2023-04-28T15:48:19.197896+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=sitename.herokuapp.com request_id=76fde61b-f759-403f-bdc0-a1a0356d19cd fwd="71.81.213.118" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=227ms status=404 bytes=343 protocol=https
```

The site runs fine on the local computer. I am a beginner and not sure what the problem could be. Any ideas to fix the issue?